# unable to get value from tag in safari

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, safari

I have the following HTML tag:

< td class="summary" id="nextday" value="2013/06/21"> NextDay: 2013/06/21 < /td>

and the following in my JS:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('nextday');
console.log(elem);
console.log(elem.id);
console.log(elem.value);
```

In IE this seems to work great, I get the following output:

**[object]**

**nextday**

**2013/06/21**

But when I run the same code in safari (using a windows 7 PC), I get the following instead:

```
< td class="summary" id="nextday" value="2013/06/21"> NextDay: 2013/06/21 < /td>
```

**nextday**

**undefined**

Any suggestions on why its behaving different in Safari than in IE, and what the proper approach should be if i want to support both browser and be able to get the nextday value from the tag?  Thanks.

edited to reflect that 'nextday' is indeed surrounded by quotes.

Comment: Shouldn't `getElementById(nextday);`  be enclosed in quotes `getElementById('nextday');`

Answer (score 0):

First of all your js should work after page is loaded. Second thing is you should change:

```
var elem = document.getElementById(nextday);
```

to

```
var elem = document.getElementById("nextday");
```

And try again in other browsers also result should be similar.

Comment: I created the following:http://jsfiddle.net/3NfCt/6/ 

it seems something else in my original page is making the IE function differently as the console.log(elem.value) shows undefined in all 3 browsers (Chrome, IE, Safari).  What would be the proper way to extract the value information as that doesn't seem to be it?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for looking at the issue.  It seems I should just be using getAttribute('value'), and that works.  For some reason jQuery didn't work, so any suggestions on why that might be would be great too.